# Нужны ли запятые при вводном слове, стоящем после тире, которое отделяет обособленный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вводные-слова

Я видела похожие вопросы, но так и не смогла найти точного ответа на свой.

> Девушка заметила, что он её разглядывает, и спросила о чём-то у
> сопровождающего мужчины(,) — скорее всего(,) менеджера.

Мне кажется, если бы не было тире, то это предложение выглядело бы так:

> Девушка заметила, что он её разглядывает, и спросила о чём-то у
> сопровождающего мужчины, скорее всего менеджера.

Но я бы хотела оставить тире, потому как мне кажется, что здесь оно возможно (поправьте, если нет). В любом случае интересует постановка запятых, когда вводное слово (сочетание) находится после тире в похожих ситуациях. **Необходимо ли не ставить запятые по причине того, что вводное слово относится к обособленному обороту, который отделён тире, а не запятой?** А если ставить, то как?

Я видела правило у Розенталя:

> *Чтобы избежать возможной неясности, иногда перед вводным
> словом, находящимся в начале обособленного оборота, ставятся запятая и
> тире, а после него — запятая: Поскольку есть ещё время, вызовем на
> экзамен дополнительно кого-нибудь, — допустим, сдающих повторно —
> ‘предположим; скажем’.*

Но в моём (или похожем) случае тире — это не дополнительный знак, который нужно добавить, а знак, изначально отделяющий обособленный оборот вместо запятой, разве нет?

Также была мысль, что тире можно заменить на скобки:

> Девушка заметила, что он её разглядывает, и спросила о чём-то у
> сопровождающего мужчины (скорее всего, менеджера).

Тогда знаки внутри скобок сохраняются, насколько я понимаю, а запятая перед вводным словом не ставится. Однако может ли тире здесь быть приближено по значению к скобкам, если скобки — парный знак, но тире тут только одно? Если бы тире было парным, было бы что-то вроде этого, наверно:

> Сопровождающий её мужчина — скорее всего, менеджер — кивнул и отошёл в
> сторону.

В итоге я не смогла сама понять этот момент и прошу помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы написала так:

*Девушка заметила, что он её разглядывает, и спросила о чём-то у сопровождающего мужчины, — **скорее всего, менеджера**.*

**Пояснение**

1. Я такие задачи решаю по правилу ПАС **методом блоков**, можно посмотреть **[здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136).** Суть метода заключается в том, что в сложных конструкциях с несколькими предикативными основами или осложненными оборотами спорный знак на стыке конструкций выбирается **по виду отношений между блоками** (в приведенном предложении между СПП и осложненным оборотом в конце фразы).
2. В данном случае можно считать, что присоединительный оборот относится **ко всему сообщению,** а не только к конкретному слову, как при постановке **тире**. Поэтому ставится единый знак  **запятая и тире.** Даже интонационно чувствуется подчеркнутая пауза.

**Примечание**

Это само **решение**, а так можете считать, что вы используете указанное вами правило **Розенталя.**

Если не использовать этот метод, то надо отыскивать подходящие для грамматики конкретного предложения **частные правила**, что бывает довольно затруднительно.

В то же время это **официальный метод,**  хотя он и не является популярным. Такое впечатление, что о нем просто не знают. Поэтому выбор за вами. Можно решать по блокам, а объяснение  давать по частным правилам.